# How innodb alter table inplace algorithm inner work?

Tags: mysql, innodb

From the [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)  , it says :

> ALTER TABLE operations are processed using one of the following
>   algorithms:
>
> COPY: Operations are performed on a copy of the original table, and
>   table data is copied from the original table to the new table row by
>   row. Concurrent DML is not permitted.
>
> INPLACE: Operations avoid copying table data but may rebuild the table
>   in place. Typically, concurrent DML is supported for InnoDB tables by
>   a DML log that is applied after table alterations are committed.

It just says mysql can dml when modify column , but how innodb alter table inplace algorithm inner work ?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many *different* cases.  I suggest you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html , then come back with a more specific question.  (Back up the version if you are using something older.)

My feeling in watching MySQL evolve over the years is this last round of Optimizations of `ALTER` has added ways to speed up just about everything in `ALTER`.  That includes avoiding rebuilding the table (when practical) and avoiding locks (when practical).

"says mysql can dml when modify column" -- Well, that depends on the modify column -- add/remove `NULL`, change `ENUM` / `DEFAULT` / etc, `ADD`/`DROP`, etc.

The first `ALTER` optimization was for adding an option to `ENUM` *at the end* and *not exceeding 255*.  That was added many versions ago -- It was rather trivial in that it changed the "meta" data only.  That can even be `INSTANT` in the new 8.0 terminology (even better than `INPLACE`).